# Update prototype links across all symbols in Adobe XD

Tags: interface-design, adobe-xd, prototyping

I am currently designing a brochure website using Adobe Experience Design.

I have converted my navigation header into a symbol so that the aesthetic can be easily changed and updated across all the different pages in my website design. Whenever a change is made, I can right click and select 'Update All Symbols', which will apply any changes across all instances of the symbol.

[image]

This does not seem to work in the same way for Prototype links. When I add a prototype link (i.e. link an element so in the prototype preview, it links to another page) and click 'Update All Symbols', the links do not change on the other pages.

The current site has 6 or so links in the navigation symbol, and 20+ pages. I do not want to manually create the prototype links across all the pages as this would be a very tedious exercise.

Is there a way to update prototype links across a symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current 1.0 version of Adobe XD, this does not appear to be possible. However, if you are in Prototype mode (not Design mode), you can copy and paste items (including groups of items), and the links on those items will copy and paste with them.

So if you have a button bar area with icons that are linked to various screens, for example, you can set it up once in Prototype mode with all the links, and then copy and paste that button bar to each screen, and the links will paste with it.

If you have overrides, be aware that this solution will pose challenges, because you will have to recreate the overrides if you ever repeat the process of copy and paste.